# django logger can't output the response content

Tags: django

I'm use django 1.4.6, I want to use the logger module integrated with django to output the response content, however, I cannot see it in the log file. 
Source sample shown here:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('__file__')
...
response = redirect(url)
logger.debug(response.content)
return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have configured your loggers, handlers, filters and formatters,
You need to call it as follows:

```
   import logging 

    # Standard instance of a logger with __name__
    stdlogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug(response.content)

    response = redirect(url)
    return response
```

The call to logging.getLogger() obtains (creating, if necessary) an instance of a logger. The logger instance is identified by a name. This name is used to identify the logger for configuration purposes.

By convention, the logger name is usually **name** .

The Python **name** syntax used for getLogger automatically assigns the package name as the logger name.

Answer (score 1):

Please show peple configuration of logging in static file

I have little change for your code

```
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Log configuation on settings.py

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
    'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s",
                'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': '/var/log/django_practices.log',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'stream': sys.stdout,
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
        },
        'loggers': {

            'name_your_app_django': {
                'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
                'level': ode'DEBUG',
            }
        }
    }
```

In my configuration log will be print in console and file name.
Note : **name_your_app_django** change to fix with your code.